# is host id size of IP address will vary between the private and public networks?

Tags: networking, ip

I understood that size of host id in the class c network is 8 bits(1 Octet)

[Classful network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)

After started exploring about private networks, in the below link

[Private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

The host id size of the IP address range belongs to the `class C` network is mentioned in as 16 byte

```
 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (16-bit block private address)
```

My Assumption:

1. Class full network is applied for both private and public IP addresses. That is ifthe IP starts with 192.168.x.x is class c network and the size of the host id in the class full network is always 8(1 octet).

Is my assumption is wrong or any theory behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Classes were deprecated in 1994. That's 20 years ago. Everything is done in VLSM using CIDR notation. What was a "Class C" is now a "/24".
2. The 192.168 RFC 1918 allocation is a /16, as noted in the "16-bit block" remark.
3. Your assumptions are based on something that was abandoned 20+ years ago.